# Is it possible to upgrade php5.2 to php5.3 when it is side by side with php4 on CentOS 4.9 via WHM(HostDime)

Tags: php, php5

They told me they don't support using that type of configuration, but we had it running from them at some point... we've been in business with them for over 8 years now. Thing is that we need to upgrade to php5.3 without loosing support for php4.

No idea how to do it. The guys at hostdime already said they wouldn't help with it. However, I know it is possible to somehow (probably recompile apache all over again?).

Comment: I noticed the easyApache setup tool has profiles one can save / upload / configure and such... Could that be a possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could compile php 4.x and 5.x separately and bind them to different php extensions (for example: .php handled by PHP 5.x and .php4 by PHP 4.x).
Consider that, in a large PHP project, you don't need to rename all file to .php4 but only the main includer (for example: `index.php`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your experience, is this achievable via WHM? Our server is hosted by HostDime, it is a private server. It would be something to be done either with current WHM tools, or perhaps via SSH command prompt?

Comment: For what I know you need to do it by SSH and you need root access (you should have if I understood). Feel free to ask me further details if needed.

Comment: Our current installation has php4 and php5.2, with this method it is possible to just upgrade the 5.2 install to a 5.3 version. Right?

Comment: Yes. You should consider the PHP 5.x the main PHP used by system (so you'll upgrade 5.2 to 5.3) and the 4.x as additional module handling .php4 files. I think you need to feel confident with system customization like compile php sources and configure the php module into apache. If you don't feel confident with these tasks, please invest some time in documentation and/or ask someone supporting you for this phase. Good luck!